# Caching of Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014

I have some structure of DB, it has 2 tables named Sections and Surgeons, which not linked between each other. I create a model, it looks like it:
[image]

well. Now I create a relationship between these 2 tables:

[image]

it's ok. Now I try to do "Update Model from Database", nothing happened. Strange. Try to remove model at all and recreate. The same, no relationship between Section and Surgeon. Why it happens? Entity Framework cached it? How to solve?
I use Visual Studio 2013 + MVC 5 + Entity Framework 6.1.2 + MS SQL 2014

ADDED:
I add scripts of these tables for sure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sections](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SectionName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sections] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Surgeons](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [SectionID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Surgeons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Surgeons]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Surgeons_Sections] FOREIGN KEY([SectionID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Sections] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Surgeons] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Surgeons_Sections]
```

Comment: When you say that you create a relationship between the two tables, do you mean in the entity model designer in Visual Studio or directly in the database?

Comment: directly in the database (I even showed diagram from DB to be sure, that relationship is created really)

Comment: I see, is it SQL Server or some other database technology that you're using?

Comment: Also on a somewhat related note, if you aren't having to work with an existing database you should seriously consider using code first instead of database first. I've generally found database first to be incredibly flaky in the past.

Comment: as I wrote in post, I use MS SQL 2014

Comment: I can't use Code First. It's a rule from customer

Comment: You have to add the column to your `Surgeons` table first, then update your models using 'update from database.'

Comment: @wahwahwah which column should I add?

Comment: If you are doing database first EF (which i think you are) you probably want to add the `SectionId` to the `Surgeons` table (like in your example.) But, how you do this is really based on your business requirements. Does every Surgeon have to have exactly one Section?

Comment: @wahwahwah I use Database First. But as you can see, the Surgeons table has SectionID. I have added sql scripts

Comment: Add a foreign key constraint - on the database side - between `Surgeons.SectionID` --> `Sections.ID`... then update your model. You might also consider making it nullable based on whether or not each Surgeon has to have at least one Section

Comment: @wahwahwah I have a foreign key constraint, you can see it on SQL Diagramm and in sql scripts!